# Asterisk use say with new mode

Tags: asterisk, playback

How do i use the new mode with say.conf?

I put in my dialplan `same => n,Playback(num:55|say)` but i get the following errors

> [Aug 24 15:12:28] WARNING[2054461][C-000001a6]: file.c:789 ast_openstream_full: File num:55|say does not exist in any format

> [Aug 24 15:12:28] WARNING[2054461][C-000001a6]: file.c:1262 ast_streamfile: Unable to open num:55|say (format (ulaw)): No such file or directory

I took the example from here https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-config-sayconf/

How can i get it to work?

Comment: That site is very dated, most of the information on it is 10-15 years old. I do not recommend its use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using '|' which was delimiter BEFORE 1.4 version(very very long time ago).

For all modern versions use comma instead of that (',')

Comment: Oh i didn't think that it is a delimiter. Is it possible to do this in the Read function (say number)?

Comment: I want to do is something like this: `Read(NumberOption,ToCallNumber&digit:1234,say&Press1&ToCallNumber&digit:5678,say&Press2,1,,2,5000)` is that possible?

Comment: No, you can't. Read accept only filenames and clearly state that in doc. But you can do digits/1&digits/2&digits/3&digits/4